# Is there any open dataset for named entity linking?

Tags: data-request, nlp, wikidata, wikipedia

[Entity linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking) is the task of detecting mentions of entities from a knowledge base in a document.

Are there any openly available datasets to train and evaluate such systems? The datasets I came across are all closed (for instance, [TAC-KBP](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/collaborations/current-projects/tac-kbp) is owned by the Linguistic Data Consortium, the [YAGO-AIDA](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/aida/downloads/) dataset requires access to the original CoNLL 2003 dataset, and so on).

The dataset should contain some text with reference annotations (for instance links to Wikipedia), and should be of reasonable size for machine learning purposes. For instance, Wikipedia dumps themselves provide this to some extent, but the wikilinks are generally not intended to be complete, so the annotations are very sparse.

Answer (score 1):

The [IITB dataset](http://natural-language-understanding.wikia.com/wiki/IITB_dataset) is quite small compared to the TAC datasets (107 documents) but it is freely available and has higher recall than off-the-shelf Wikipedia pages. It can be downloaded at https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~soumen/doc/CSAW/Annot/

Comment: The RDF2NLP project also lists some datasets in the NIF format - not all of them are relevant for Entity Linking though: http://dashboard.nlp2rdf.aksw.org/